# How to add type in typescript using vue-router

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

what is the type of router here?

```
import { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router'

const moduleRoute: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
    {
        path: '/user',
        component: () => import('./HomeModule.vue'),
        children: [

        ]
    }
]

export default router => {
    router.addRoute(moduleRoute)
}
```

all I want is the type of the exportable router

Answer (score 0):

The type of the router is Router from 'vue-router'.
You can use it as:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import type { Router } from 'vue-router';
const router: Router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [],
});
```

Here is your corrected code:

```
import type { RouteRecordRaw, Router } from 'vue-router';

const moduleRoute: RouteRecordRaw = {
  path: '/user',
  component: () => import('./YourView.vue'),
  children: [],
};

export default (router: Router) => {
  router.addRoute(moduleRoute);
};
```